How to implement in pytorch - numpy's .unique WITH(!) return_index = True?
In  numpy.unique there is an option return_index=True - which returns positions of unique elements (first occurrence - if several).
Unfortunately, there is no such option in torch.unique !
Question: What are the fast and torch-style ways to get indexes of the unique elements ?
=====================
More generally my issue is the following: I have two vectors v1, v2, and I want to get positions of those elements in v2, which are not in v1 and also for repeated elements I need only one position.   Numpy's unique with return_index = True immediately gives the solution.  How to do it in torch ? If we know that vector v1 is sorted, can it be used to speed up the process ?

You might want to have a look at the answer to this question. Regarding the fact that v1 is sorted, you might want to check if torch.unique_consecutive() makes sense to use.

You can achieve this in PyTorch with the following approach:
def get_unique_elements_first_idx(tensor):
    # sort tensor
    sorted_tensor, indices = torch.sort(tensor)
    # find position of jumps
    unique_mask = torch.cat((torch.tensor([True]), sorted_tensor[1:] != sorted_tensor[:-1]))
    return indices[unique_mask]

Example usage:
v1 = torch.tensor([2, 3, 3])
v2 = torch.tensor([1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 10, 4, 6, 4])

# Mask to find elements in v2 that are not in v1
mask = ~torch.isin(v2, v1)
v2_without_v1 = v2[mask]

# Get unique elements and their first indices
unique_indices = get_unique_elements_first_idx(v2_without_v1)

print(unique_indices)           #[0, 3, 1, 2]
print(v2[mask][unique_indices]) #[1, 4, 6, 10]

P.S. On my computer, the function processes a vector of size 10 million in about (1.1 ± 0.1)s.

A caveat: this will fail for repeated nan values, as nan != nan evaluates to True. I still thinks it's a viable solution though, if one keeps this caveat in mind.

Thanks for the great answer ! Some experiments: ".isin" seems to work pretty slow - see https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/growth-3-permutations-torch-gpu?scriptVersionId=190357514&cellId=34 . Speed-up can be achieved by fist taking unique elements, and then using option assume_unique = True, see https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/growth-3-permutations-torch-gpu?scriptVersionId=190357872&cellId=34

In the function get_unique_elements_first_idx(tensor) , it is better to use "stable = True": torch.sort(tensor, stable = True) , otherwise it is not fully compatible with numpy.unique( return_index = True )
